# Cannot connect Samsung Galaxy Y Duos to laptop via USB cable

Tags: windows-8, usb, android, cable

While I am connecting my phone to my laptop neither the laptop nor the phone can detect each other. By not recognizing I want to mean nothing happens after connecting. It seems that I have not connected the mobile to laptop. No error is coming. 'Unknown Device' error is also **NOT** coming. Just the phone is charging.

- I have tried dialing  *#7284#. But only a black screen is coming.
- I have downloaded the driver from internet & installed it. Still the 
  same problem.
- This problem starts when I connect it to my laptop which has 
  windows 8. It works fine in windows XP in my desktop PC (i.e when I connect I get the 'USB Connected' notification in my phone which I don't get when I connect it to my laptop (win 8).
- No problem in device manager of my laptop after connecting the phone. It is also showing fine.

So how to connect my Samsung Galaxy Y Duos to Laptop via USB cable?

Comment: Are you using the same USB cable with both the notebook and the desktop? If you plug another USB device into the Win8 notebook, does it work as expected?

Comment: Yes. Other usb devices are working fine in win 8 notebook. @techie007

Comment: I dont know what happned but I was connecting my phone in my USB 3.0 port of my laptop and it was not connecting. But suddenly I plugged it into the USB 2.0 port then it started working properly. Dont know what happned but I am happy :)

Comment: Certain devices will not work with USB3 ports (essentially, most devices manufactured <2013... some will simply not work at all, whereas others will allow `adb` and file level access, but not allow flashing via a USB3 port [XT926 Rzr Maxx HD for instance]).  However, if one has also tried a USB2 port, verify the USB connection is set to a connection option that allows file access (i.e. not "Charge Only").

Answer (score 0):

You might want to download Samsung Kies to ensure the right drivers are installed. www.samsung.com/kies -- I think Kies3 is only for more recent phones, but it'll tell you what to do.

Alternatively, consider AirDroid - www.airdroid.com - it's an Android app that lets you transfer files (and LOTS besides) through your web browser, no wires/drivers required.

Comment: Also another option is ES File Explorer which can allow you to FTP onto your mobile device and vice versa

Comment: All android phone should support file level access over `adb`, for example `adb shell` for a terminal, `adb push -p source device` to transfer file(s) to the the device, or `adb pull -p device destination` to transfer file(s) from the device

Answer (score 0):

Go to phone settings > Developer options > USB debugging and turn it on.

OR

Check whether your USB cable is working or not.

And if still not working then factory reset ur phone.

This might solve your problem.